# Printing Combinations without Repeats in R

Tags: r, combinatorics

I would like to get the following printout in R:

```
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,3,4

2,1,3
2,1,4
2,3,4

3,1,2
3,1,4
3,2,4

4,1,2
4,1,3
4,2,3
```

Something along the lines of:

```
for (main in 1:4){
  for (i in 1:4) {
    if (i != main){
      for (j in 1:4){
        if (j != main & j != i){print main,i,j}}}}}
```

And I would like to have the above 12 results in a vector. Thank you.

Comment: Use `combn(1:4,3)` if you want *combinations* -- but you seem to be asking about *permuations*. Also why `1, 2, 4` and `2, 1, 4` and `4, 1, 2` but not any of the other permutations of `{1,2,4}`. The logic behind your scheme isn't clear to me.

Comment: I am eventually going to be using a function that takes the distance between the first point and the divergence between the second two. Thus 1,2,4 and 2,1,4 are different but 1,2,4 and 1,4,2 are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is an odd combination between permutations and combinations. Here a possible solution:

```
Reduce(rbind,
  lapply(1:4, function(i){
    t(rbind(i, combn((1:4)[-i], 2)))
  })
)
#>       i    
#>  [1,] 1 2 3
#>  [2,] 1 2 4
#>  [3,] 1 3 4
#>  [4,] 2 1 3
#>  [5,] 2 1 4
#>  [6,] 2 3 4
#>  [7,] 3 1 2
#>  [8,] 3 1 4
#>  [9,] 3 2 4
#> [10,] 4 1 2
#> [11,] 4 1 3
#> [12,] 4 2 3
```